# Python: create a mask with unknown shape

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, masking, edge-detection

I'm trying to extract a mask with an "unknown" shape. I'm going to explain my self better:

My original data consists of a matrix with NaNs that, more or less, surround the true data. I have used a sobel operator to detect the edge:

```
#data is a matrix with Nan
mask = np.isnan(data)
data[mask] = 0
data[~mask] = 1 
out = sobel(data) #sobel is a function that returns the gradient
```

[image: sobel output]

In figure the output of sobel operation is reported. Since the original data has also NaNs among true data, sobel operator detect inner edges. 
I want to try a method to detect only the outer edges (the figure that looks like a rhombus). Consider that not only this shape can vary (it can be a square or a rectangle), but also the position can change (i.e. can be decentered, or very small respect to the image dimension). The result that I would obtain should be a mask with all outer pixel set to True (or False), while all inner pixel set to False (or True).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible, partial, solution is using an `opening` operation, defined as an erosion followed by a dilation. I used the one provided by `skimage`:

```
from skimage.morphology import opening
#data has shape shape_1, shape_2
mask_data = np.ones((shape_1, shape_2), dtype=bool)
mask = np.isnan(data)
mask_data[_mask] = 0
mask_data = opening(mask_data).astype(bool)
```

Such method returns something that is similar to what I'm looking for. As the picture suggests, this actually leaves some black inner dots, but it is the best I found.

[image]